# Database Schema for Blank Database is large. 20MB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, schema

Is it normal for blank databases with just schema to be large? Or is there a way that I can reduce the size of the initial database?

Comment: Are specific objects taking up space? Or are you just talking about the .mdf file? If the latter, then why do you care if an empty database takes up 4 MB, or 20 MB, or 64 MB? You're going to fill it with data, right? At which point it should start getting a lot bigger than that? Are you storing your database on a drive where 20 MB is a serious space-threatening hardship? You can likely make it smaller, if it really is empty, but doing so is kind of pointless - if you're going to put data into it, it's going to grow - what were you able to do with < 20 MB of free space in the meantime?

Comment: If I am going to add thousands of blank DBs into production, space matters.

Comment: Well (1) say that in your question, and (2) are you going to add thousands of blank DBs ***that will never, ever grow***? Why? How exactly are you creating the database? What objects are in model?

Comment: They may sit for a while in production before being assigned, so while sitting the least amount of space used would be great. There are outside factors that motivate my inquiry, such as the line of business and upper level management. I hope you understand where I am coming from.

Comment: If you don't have the space to store thousands of _empty_ databases, how can you store them if they **do** contain data?

Comment: Sometimes (actually often) "line of business" and upper level management ask for things that can't be done.  It is better to tell them that now while you can still do it a different way then wait to tell them everything is broken.

Answer (score 11):

If you create a database without specifying a file size, the size is mapped from model. You can see what this is by running:

```
EXEC model.sys.sp_helpfile;
-- on my system, size of primary data file -> 3264 KB
```

Now, if I create a database just using `CREATE DATABASE`, I get an exact replica of those files.

```
CREATE DATABASE [floob1];
GO
EXEC floob1.sys.sp_helpfile;
-- size of primary data file -> 3264 KB
```

I can try to shrink it after the fact, and it will shrink some, but not entirely.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(floob1, 1);
GO
EXEC floob1.sys.sp_helpfile;
-- size of primary data file -> 2368 KB
```

So you can do that, but perhaps you should first find out what's in your `model` database and why it's 20 MB. Perhaps you can fix this problem by removing objects and/or shrinking *that* file. If shrinking the file doesn't reduce the size, then check for objects:

```
SELECT s.name, t.name, rows = SUM(p.rows)
  FROM model.sys.partitions AS p
  INNER JOIN model.sys.objects AS t
    ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN model.sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE p.index_id IN (0,1)
  ORDER BY rows DESC;

SELECT s.name, o.name, codesize = DATALENGTH(m.definition)
  FROM sys.objects AS o
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
    ON o.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
  ORDER BY codesize DESC;
```

It's possible that objects were created there by mistake (in which case drop them), or have more rows than they should (in which case prune them and rebuild).

Note that if you try to override `model` and make a smaller database, you can't:

```
CREATE DATABASE [floob2]
ON (NAME = floob2_data, 
  FILENAME = 'C:\...wherever...\floob2.mdf',
  SIZE = 1MB, FILEGROWTH = 2MB);
```

This results in an error:

> Msg 1803, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   
> The CREATE DATABASE statement failed. The primary file must be at least 4 MB to accommodate a copy of the model database.

I assume you'll get a similar error if you try to create a database with an explicit data file < 20 MB, because it sounds like your `model` database is about 20 MB. So going back to my previous point, you're going to need to dig in and see why `model` is 20 MB, and fix that. (And note that I have no idea how you're measuring 20 MB - it could be the log file, for all I know, so you may need to look at that file instead.)

Of course, if space is a real issue and you put thousands of databases there under the assumption that they'll never grow, and then they all start growing, this is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

New databases are based on the Model db. It is possible to reduce the size of database and log files by shrinking, but this will likely severely fragment any existing indexes.

Comment: what are some ways to reduce model DB?